# Unable to Access ubuntu 20.04 server Remotely using RDP

Tags: networking, server, gnome, rdp

I recently installed Ubuntu Server Version 20.04. From the Terminal I install the Gnome Desktop. The desktop works except that I am unable access the Server using remote desktop. SSH works fine. When I am in the settings window and I go to into sharing the screen sharing button  is turned off . [Screen sharing Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFCXm.jpg)

I tried to run the Gnome settings from the terminal with admin rights but I got the same result. However in the terminal window I got the following error messages:

> (gnome-control-center:14437): sharing-cc-panel-WARNING **: 17:11:00.051: couldn't list networks: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing was not provided by any .service files

(gnome-control-center:14437): sharing-cc-panel-WARNING **: 17:11:00.054: couldn't list networks: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing was not provided by any .service files

(gnome-control-center:14437): sharing-cc-panel-WARNING **: 17:11:28.849: Failed to enable service vino-server: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing was not provided by any .service files

(gnome-control-center:14437): sharing-cc-panel-WARNING **: 17:11:28.850: couldn't list networks: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing was not provided by any .service files
User@server01:~$

> Blockquote

I'm lost as what these error messages mean because the only network connection I have to this sever is a single NIC card that's set to DHCP.

Answer (score 1):

I encounter the exact same error messages when I try to enable Screen Sharing on a remote host running Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 after I log in to that remote host using `ssh -X`. This is a different situation from yours, but it could be related.

I have reported the issue to [upstream gnome-control-center](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/-/issues/999) and you may want to follow it.

PS: Screen Sharing in Ubuntu is through VNC, not RDP.

Answer (score 0):

At first, I installed XRDP, and linked it with MS remote.
It worked. Then, I installed TIGHTvncserver and used REALVNC to link, and it is worked, too.

But, the remote didn't work, and the settings sharing-remote is lost.